# Adobe Flash Builder 4: HTTP Service: What to return?

Tags: php, flash, adobe, builder

I'm having trouble figuring out what my Flex Project is expecting from my PHP file in-relation to HTTP Service. Can anyone give a link or an example as to what the PHP file should return? I already configured the return type of the Operation to String. Then on my PHP file, I put in a simple line of code

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

but the problem is, whenever I try to test the Operation, Flash Builder keeps telling me ***InvocationTargetException:The response is not a valid XML or a JSON string***

I want to see a working example of interactions between a Flex Project and an HTTP Service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Builder expects an XML or JSON as a result.
So in your php file you'll have to wrap the result as a XML (or JSON):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theresult>
      <thestring>hello world</thestring>
</theresult>
```